# Битрикс: как подружить фиксированное меню и $APPLICATION->ShowPanel()?

Tags: php, битрикс, меню, if

Натягиваю сайт на Битрикс и вставляю в код конструкцию для отображения административной панели:

```
<? $APPLICATION->ShowPanel(); ?>
```

Но поскольку на сайте есть фиксированное меню, оно перекрывает большую часть панели, и пользоваться ей полноценно невозможно.

Теоретически можно панель переместить на первый план, но тогда не будет видно меню.

Есть ли какой-то способ подружить их? Чтобы когда панель отображается, весь сайт (в том числе фиксированное меню) смещался вниз?

Хотел написать проверку типа:

```
<? if($APPLICATION->ShowPanel()) {
    // здесь вариант смещения сайта вниз
}?>
```

но в таком виде, разумеется, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете проверять, админ ли пользователь, и смещать ему сайт вниз. Конструкцией

`global $USER; if ($USER->IsAdmin()){}`.

Но вообще, я обычно панель вставляю сразу после `<body>`, а весь контент сайта у меня в `<div id="wrapper">`. В таком случае проблем подобных не возникнет. Хотя, в вашем случае, если меню через `position:fixed; top:0;` установлено, то да, будет наложение.

Comment: Да, у меня именно position: fixed, и wrapper не помог бы. А вот if ($USER->IsAdmin()){} - то что надо! спасибо.